# How can I set the default number format in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm working with Clojure on some binary formats in which it makes sense to inspect numbers that are hex formatted (`0x10`). How can I configure Clojure to render numbers as hex, by default? This is probably most relevant to me while in a REPL, but I'm also interested in more general mechanisms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clojure uses to multi-methods for printing data: `print-method` (intended to provide output to be read by humans) and `print-dup` (that produces output that can be parsed with read).

Thus for REPL you can simply provide your implementation of print-method for `java.lang.Number`s like in the REPL session below:

```
123
=> 123

(prn 123)
123
=> 123

(defmethod print-method Number
  [n ^java.io.Writer w]
  (.write w (format "0x%X" n)))
=> #object[clojure.lang.MultiFn 0x52ad430a "clojure.lang.MultiFn@52ad430a"]

123
=> 0x7B

(prn 123)
0x7B
=> nil
```

Comment: this works perfectly, including within a CIDER session. thanks!